# Oracle Database Sql Developer

Tags: oracle

I have installed 18C. it was running fine. After a couple of weeks - when i re-started the client - Oracle SQL Devloper produced the following error:

> "RA-12528: TNS:listener: all appropriate instances are blocking new connections".

What is the solution to this error? Re-install oracle? Re-install Oracle SQL developer on the client? Any alternative? Please help.

I have used google, but in vain.

Answer (score 0):

Check the status of the listener by

```
[oracle@hostname ~]$ lsnrctl
```

LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 11.2.0.3.0 - Production on 24-APR-2017 15:33:49

Copyright (c) 1991, 2011, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Welcome to LSNRCTL, type "help" for information.

```
LSNRCTL> status
```

One method that should resolve this problem is to restart (bounce) the LISTENER:

```
LSNRCTL> stop
LSNRCTL> start
```

Then restart your instance:

```
sqlplus with sysdba privileges

SQL> startup
```

Comment: Hi respected friend , i did all these trick but in vain . any more or suggestions. please help as it waist my time.